# How to remove anchor links from headers in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, kramdown

In Github, when you create an h2 or smaller header (##, ###, ...) there is an anchor link thing that is automatically generated to the right of the header. When you click this anchor, it links you to the page with that header at the top of the page (www.myurl#myheader).

Is it possible to remove this anchor?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because when you attempt to center these headers, it centers taking into account the clickable anchor thing as part of the header. The result is the header is not truly centered.

Comment: Try removing the styling for the hyperlink in the header.

Comment: I just applied `text-align: center` to a h3 heading in github and it centered as expected. Not sure what you're seeing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable Kramdown's [auto-ids](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html#option-auto-ids) option. Depending on how you are using Kramdown, there are a number of ways in which to do so:

### Command Line

If you are using Kramdown from the command line, simply include the `--no-auto-ids` option:

```
kramdown --no-auto-ids
```

### Ruby Code

If you are calling Kramdown from your own Ruby code, set `auto_ids: false`:

```rb
Kramdown::Document.new(source_text, {auto_ids: false})
```

### From within a document

You can also override the default settings from within a document for the document only. Include the following in the document on a line by itself:

```
{::options auto_ids="false" /}
```

### GitHub Pages

The question mentions GitHub. Assuming this is referring to GitHub Pages with Jekyll (as that is the [only place GitHub makes use of Kramdown](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-a-markdown-processor-for-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll)), you can [set Kramdown options](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown) in your `_config.yml` file:

```
markdown: kramdown
auto_ids: false
```

Note that if you are using GFM on GitHub Pages, or if you are using any other GitHub service except GitHub Pages, this option is not available as GFM does not offer such an option.

Comment: Thanks!! Such a comprehensive answer! I would upvote you but I don't have the power yet.

Comment: As you asked the question, you should be able to "accept" an answer to the question if it sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, just did that.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to answer my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828654/background-highlight-text-in-a-code-block