# Background highlight text in a code block?

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-pages, kramdown

My goal is to be able to display something like this:

[image]

I want to **background highlight** a piece of code inside a code block that already has **syntax highlighting**. I want to do this on a markdown file I have on Github that is hosted on Github Pages (can use kramdown markdown, html, css).

I am aware that you can have **syntax highlighting** inside a code block doing something like this:

````
```java
int foo (void) {
    int i;
}
```
````

I am also aware that I can **background highlight** text inside a code block by doing something like this:

```
<pre><code>int foo (void) {
    <span style="background-color:yellow">int i;</span>
}
</code></pre>
```

But how do I combine these two things?

Comment: I am aware I could just do this in a word processor, screenshot it, and embed the screenshot image into my markdown file. However, you can't select text in images, so I am wondering if there is a less hacky way of doing this using markdown, html, and/or css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Google's [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) to color the code. It will colorize all code with the class `prettyprint`. Then you can use a `<span>` tag to set the background color.

```css
pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
  <pre>
    <code class="prettyprint">
 int foo (void) {
   <span style="background-color:yellow">int i;</span>
 }
 // Yay code and it has colors
    </code>
  </pre>
```